# На старых версиях браузеров, не запускается ajax запрос

Tags: javascript, ajax

При отправки формы с ajax. Форма отправляется, но не выполняется ajax в консоле пишет
HTML1527: Ожидается DOCTYPE. Рекомендуется добавить допустимый HTML5 DOCTYPE: "".
В HTML стоит тип

Сам AJAX:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        var $form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: $form.serialize(),
            beforeSend: () => {
                document.getElementsByName('form')[0].reset();
            },
            success: () => {
                console.log("success")
                let a = document.querySelector(".message");
                a.classList.remove("none");
                a.classList.add("show"); exit();
            },
            error: () => {
                console.log("error");
                alert("Ошибка");
            }
        })
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Добавлял mimeType: "text/html" толку ноль. Сейчас заметил что тот же IE ругается на синтекс ошибку на 8 строке. Помогите пжл

Comment: Ie не знает про стрелочные функции. Перепишите на обычные

Comment: Переписал фунции, один фиг выдает тоже самое

Comment: Ну покажите что переписали и что выдаёт?

Comment: $(function () {
 $('form').submit(function (e) {
  var $form = $(this);
  $.ajax({
   type: $form.attr('method'),
   url: $form.attr('action'),
   data: $form.serialize(),
   beforeSend: function () {
    document.getElementsByName('form')[0].reset();
   },
   success: function () {

    console.log("success")
    let a = document.querySelector(".message");
    a.classList.remove("none");
    a.classList.add("show"); exit();
   },
   error: function () {
    console.log("error");
    alert("Ошибка");
   }
  })
  e.preventDefault();
 });
});

Comment: HTML1527: Ожидается DOCTYPE. Рекомендуется добавить допустимый HTML5 DOCTYPE: "". В HTML пишет тоже самое

Comment: «Ожидается DOCTYPE» скорее всего не имеет никакого отношения к ошибке. Почему вы считаете что ajax не работает?

Comment: При отправки формы он переходит на страницу php. А код работает так: При отправки, Ajax функция при выполнение показывает всплывающие окно, и все это без перезагрузки страницы. Это на IE не срабатывает, пишет в консоле ошибку которую указал сверху. На других браузерах все четко.